# Is there a keyboard shortcut to uncheck, not toggle, a checkbox?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, autohotkey

If looking at a webpage checkbox you know whether it needs to be toggled with mouse or spacebar to uncheck. However, with tools that simulate keyboard usage I am not aware of a way to definitively uncheck a checkbox without using javascript. Is there a keyboard shortcut or approach I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

An overlooked keyboard shortcut?  Probably not.

But this is also a more generalized problem than just using checkboxes on a web page--sometimes there is simply no programmatically good way to set a toggled input to a definitive actual value that you'd like it to be.  In those cases try being creative to see if you can find some other combination of items that will definitively set it one way or the other, and then execute the toggle.  In other words, if there is anything that will set the form or checkbox a certain way, then possibly execute that first (sometimes you'll find some functionality like this, and other times it just doesn't exist).

Another option requiring slightly more effort is to actually 'look' at the screen (programmatically) in a certain spot, retrieve the pixel color, or do an image search, and then in those cases for example, you could check to see if the box is checked or filled, and then execute a toggle as-needed (or not). These types of checks are relatively doable in Autohotkey.